# Why the nested 'for' loop is not working in the below program?

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>

#include<conio.h>

void main()
{
    int m,a,i,b;

    printf("Enter the number upto which the prime number is to be displayed:");
    scanf("%d",&m);

    for(a=1;a<=m;a++)
    {
        for(i=1;i<=a;i++)
        {
            if(a%i==0)
            {
                b++;
            }
        }
        if(b==2)
        {
            printf("\t%d",a);
        }
    }
    getch();
}
```

Comment: which part not working? what you expect and what you got? can you elaborate more?

Comment: Anyone please answer for this...

Comment: considered formatting your code?

Comment: @Bala chander: Answer what? "Not working" is not a meaningful description of the problem.

Comment: Initialize vairable b and put it inside the second for-loop if it is there. It's inside the main for-loop

Comment: You have not initialized b and instead of initializing you increase this value by one as b++. Again you should share the algorithm you followed to find the prime number, which will make sense to other to help you.

Comment: ok, after initialising b as 0 if i am giving the input number as 10 means it should print the prime numbers upto 10, but it is showing nothing in the output screen.

Comment: but i can get the expected output for the below program,where i have used a function in it,and in that function i have used the second for loop.#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
void fun(int z);
void main()
{
int m,a;
clrscr();
printf("Enter the number upto which the prime number is to be displayed:");
scanf("%d",&m);
for(a=1;a<=m;a++)
{
fun(a);
}
getch();
}
void fun(int z)
{
int i,b=0;
for(i=1;i<=z;i++)
{
if(z%i==0)
{
b++;
}
}
if(b==2)
{
printf("\t%d",z);
}
}

Comment: my question is both the programs have similar functioning but if i am using the second for loop in a separate function means i can get the expected output,but not in first program. Why this happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

initialize `b` at the beginning of your code, and inside the loop:

```
#include<stdio.h>

#include<conio.h>

void main() 
{
    int m,a,i,b=0; // initialize b

    printf("Enter the number upto which the prime number is to be displayed:");
    scanf("%d",&m);

    for(a=1;a<=m;a++) 
    {
        for(i=1;i<=a;i++)
        { 
            if(a%i==0) 
            {
                b++;
            }
        }
        if(b==2)
        { 
            printf("\t%d",a);
        }

        b=0; // re-initialize
    } 
    getch();
}
```

Comment: ok, after initialising b as 0 if i am giving the input number as 10 means it should print the prime numbers upto 10, but it is showing nothing in the output screen.

Comment: but i can get the expected output for the below program,where i have used a function in it,and in that function i have used the second for loop.#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
void fun(int z);
void main()
{
int m,a;
clrscr();
printf("Enter the number upto which the prime number is to be displayed:");
scanf("%d",&m);
for(a=1;a<=m;a++)
{
fun(a);
}
getch();
}
void fun(int z)
{
int i,b=0;
for(i=1;i<=z;i++)
{
if(z%i==0)
{
b++;
}
}
if(b==2)
{
printf("\t%d",z);
}
}

Comment: @Balachander did you re-initialize the variable `b=0` as `chouaib` has suggested
OR
initialize `b` only once just after the 1st for loop like below:
for(a=1;a<=m;a++) 
    {
        b=0;
        .
        .

Comment: my question is both the programs have similar functioning but if i am using the second for loop in a separate function means i can get the expected output,but not in first program. Why this happens?

Comment: @Balachander your question is correct. And asnwer to your question is that when you use function, in that case variable `b` becomes local to that function only and is initialized every time you call the function so you get the proper output. You yourself have initialized the variable `b` as `int i,b=0;` at the start of the function.

Answer (score 0):

You do `b++` before you initialize `b`. Uninitialized (non-static) local variables have an indeterminate value, and using them in operations leads to [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: ok, after initialising b as 0 if i am giving the input number as 10 means it should print the prime numbers upto 10, but it is showing nothing in the output screen.

Comment: but i can get the expected output for the below program,where i have used a function in it,and in that function i have used the second for loop.

#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
void fun(int z);
void main()
{
int m,a;
clrscr();
printf("Enter the number upto which the prime number is to be displayed:");
scanf("%d",&m);
for(a=1;a<=m;a++)
{
fun(a);
}
getch();
}
void fun(int z)
{
int i,b=0;
for(i=1;i<=z;i++)
{
if(z%i==0)
{
b++;
}
}
if(b==2)
{
printf("\t%d",z);
}
}

Comment: my question is both the programs have similar functioning but if i am using the second for loop in a separate function means i can get the expected output,but not in first program. Why this happens?